# Tracing input modification with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, dom

I have an input that is having it's value stripped out by some jQuery somewhere, but I do not know what it is, so I was hoping I could just trace the dom object, and get a log of whatever has modified the object.

I am hoping to get a log like:

```
$('#selector').val('123') called in funcName file.js line 246
```

Is there anything that exists like this?

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint in the jquery.val method

Answer (score 0):

I'm reticent to post this, but have you considered removing the DOM element and then checking to see where any scripts fail to access it in the first place? Not as straight forward as you're looking for, but may produce the same result.

Or maybe, you could try overriding jQuery's .val() function...

I can think of things that inspect events but not value/access-- its a good question.

Comment: Yeah I had tried that, I found the answer in the end, it was a script that was reacting to a data-attribute, so, when the dom element was removed, the script was not invoked, hence, no error! difficult one to trace!